# Stuck at "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, react-props

I'm testing out the `gatsby-source-wordpress` plugin from [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/?=), and I'm trying to get my menu to fetch the links from my Wordpress site.

I've managed to get all of the Wordpress schemas to come up in GraphiQL, and copied the GQL code from there.

I've made a Layout component, where I've tried most of what I can to make it work. However, I keep getting *TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined* when I deploy my Gatsby site to localhost.

Anyone ever come across this before? I'm kinda new to GraphQL and all that, so I honestly have no clue what's wrong, or if it's even GraphQL that's causing this. Any help is greatly appreciated! *(Sorry if this is a really simple fix, and I'm just being ignorant)*

I've searched through Google, Stack Overflow, Youtube, and anywhere else I could think of.

## Code

#### Layout

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
// import Image from "gatsby"

import Header from "../Header";
import MainMenu from "../Nav";
// import Aside from "../Aside"
// import Footer from "../Footer";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const menu = this.props.data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems;
  return (

    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query menuQuery {
          allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                name
                items {
                  title
                  object_slug
                  url
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `}

      render={menu => (
        <>
          <Header>
            <MainMenu menu="{data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems}" />
          </Header>
          <div className="Layout">
            <main>{children}</main>
          </div>
          <footer>Footer</footer>
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
};

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

export default Layout;
```

#### Menu component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import { Link } from "gatsby";

class MainMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    const data = this.props.data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems;
    console.log(data);

    return (
      <nav className="main-menu">
        <ul>
          <p>Test</p>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default MainMenu;
```

**Expected result:** The site renders on `localhost:8000`
**Error messages I recieve:**

```sh
src/components/Layout/index.js:11
   8 | // import Aside from "../Aside"
   9 | // import Footer from "../Footer";
  10 | 
> 11 | const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  12 |   const menu = this.props.data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems;
  13 |   return (
  14 |     <StaticQuery
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing `this.props` in a function based component. Change your declaration to

```
const Layout = ({ children, data }) => {
    const menu = data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems;
```

Or explicitly declare `props` and `destructure` the properties you want

```
const Layout = props => {
    const { data, children, ...rest } = props
    const menu = data.allWordpressWpApiMenusMenusItems;
```